# Gradient Adjustments

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gradient

I'm not sure if this kind of question fits in here but, I'm trying – for quite some time I confess – recreate a gradient spec from a very small source to use in a another, larger.

I'm not very good with design to say the least, so I tried think logically and then I picked the colors of the first and last pixels of the source image:

[image: Source]

But when replicating, even adjusting Photoshop's Gradient Overlay settings (see below) it was... pale, although in here, with the white background, they look very close.

[image: Attempt]

These are settings I used, trying to match:

[image: Settings]

How could I solve this?

Comment: You have the Scale of the Gradient overlay set at 150%. Try setting it to 100%

Answer (score 1):

I don't see this being much of an issue.  In this attached image, The original gradient is on the left and my re-create is on the right.

[image]

Really, all I did was using my eyedropper tool, I selected the darkest green in the original and added that to my swatches panel and the same thing for the lightest green.  From there, all I needed to do was add a gradient overlay in my layers panel, and just add a couple of more sliders which will automatically add lighter colors appropriately.

If I spent five more minutes adjusting the gradient sliders I could have got it identical.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So far those gradients really looks alike. That's why people don't know what to answer. With provided information I can only suggest you to adjust gradient and choose colors one tone brighter.